# How edit the value of post inside serializer in Django?

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and Django Rest Framework. Below the `Register` serializer is given and the `user`'s birthday in `datetime` format. However the birthdate sent inside post is in `timestamp` format.
I want to convert `timestamp` that posted from user's device to `datetime` inside serializer. How to do it?

```
class Register_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      
        password2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Tuser
            fields = [Constants.EMAIL, Constants.PASSWORD, Constants.PASSWORD2, Constants.BIRTH_DATE]
            extra_kwargs = {
                "password": {"write_only": True}
            }
```

Comment: Why you don’t convert timestamp to datetime in save function?

Comment: Save works after is_valid. Before save I need to convert timestamp to datetime. Save totally useless here. I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this,

```
class CustomField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data )

class Register_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    birthday = CustomField() 
    
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Tuser
        fields = [Constants.EMAIL, Constants.PASSWORD, Constants.PASSWORD2, Constants.BIRTH_DATE]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "password": {"write_only": True}
        }
```

Comment: An error occurred: Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'

Comment: Can you show your script what you tried?

Comment: Sorry there is not error. Thanks for the answer